# GridView update and delete statements corrupted

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Im relatively new to asp.net and so to the GridView and Im having hard time accomplish the following task:
T have three tables in my database:

```
    Bookings    
    --------------------------------------------------------
    id  |   start_date  |   end_date   |  user_id  | pet_id
    ----|---------------|--------------|-----------|--------
    1   |   01/04/2011  |  01/04/2011  |     1     |    2
    --------------------------------------------------------

    Pets    
    ---------------------------------------------------------
     id  |  name       | species  |  owner_id  | caretaker_id
    -----|-------------|----------|------------|-------------
      1  |  samplename |   dog    |      1     |     2
    ---------------------------------------------------------

    Users    
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
      id  |  email               | first_name  |  last_name   | password
    ------|----------------------|-------------|--------------|-------------
       1  |  test@test.gmail.com |   Name      |      Surname | passwordhere
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What Im trying to do is use the data grid to display the information from bookings table, make it editable so that the user can edit bookings for his pet. The initial try with the automatic sql statements worked fine, `SELECT * from [bookings]` returned the bookings table and I was able to delete and update the rows.
I decided to use new select query so that the user will clearly see the name of his pet and his name as an owner instead of numbers. I used the following select query which works great:

```
    select start_date, end_date, usr.first_name AS 'Owner', pets.name AS 'Pet name' from  
    bookings AS bookings left join users AS usr ON bookings.user_id=usr.id left join
    pets AS pets ON pets.id=bookings.pet_id

    Output    
        ----------------------------------------------------------
           start_date  |  end_date   | Owner       |  Pet name   | 
        ---------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
           01/04/2011  |  01/04/2011 |   Name      |  samplename | 
        ----------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Now here comes the problem: from the time I update the select query in my GridView to the mentioned one, no delete and update statements work. Of course I would provide the custom ones but no matter what I try it always returns an error `incorrect syntax near nvarchar`.
I'm also unsure if the pet_id column is an integer or should be a string since it is showing the name of pet in the new join select instead of its id?

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here. I appreciate any help. The code for the GridView below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="start_date" HeaderText="start_date" SortExpression="start_date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="end_date" HeaderText="end_date" SortExpression="end_date" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Owner" HeaderText="Owner" SortExpression="Owner" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Pet name" HeaderText="Pet name" SortExpression="Pet name" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:pph_database %>" SelectCommand="select start_date, end_date, usr.first_name AS 'Owner', pets.name AS 'Pet name' from bookings AS bookings left join users AS usr ON bookings.user_id=usr.id left join pets AS pets ON pets.id=bookings.pet_id" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [bookings] SET [start_date] = @start_date, [end_date] = @end_date, [user_id] = @user_id, [pet_id] = @pet_id WHERE [id] = @id" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [bookings] WHERE [id] = @id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [bookings] ([start_date], [end_date], [user_id], [pet_id]) VALUES (@start_date, @end_date, @user_id, @pet_id)">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="start_date" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="end_date" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="user_id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="pet_id" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="start_date" />
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="end_date" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="user_id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="pet_id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Where are OnRowDeleting, OnRowEditing, OnRowUpdating Events in your GridView?

Comment: I guess they are not there at all, everything I have has been posted above. The interresting thing is that the queries work on original setting but if I make the select with joins, even the simplest UPDATE statement

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will do like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataMember="Table"
   EnableModelValidation="True" CssClass = "GridViewStyle" 
   OnRowDeleting = "dataViewRowDeleting" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True"
   OnRowEditing = "dataViewRowEditing" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
   OnRowUpdating = "dataViewRowUpdating"> 
    <Columns>
    ...
    </Columns>           
</asp:GridView>
```

You can associate events dataViewRowDeleting with row deleting and dataViewRowEditing with row editing.